# WordPress check for category archive query in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added an action on 'pre_get_posts' in that I am checking if the query is for 'product' post type. How can I check if the query is also for category archive page.

```
if (!is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('product') && $query->is_main_query()){}
```

I have checked with

```
if (!is_admin() && (is_post_type_archive('product') || is_category())&& $query->is_main_query()){}
```

but that didn't worked.

I need to modify the query for the category page e.g http://localhost/projects/lap/product-category/interior/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use is_product_category() if its return true then page is product category page.

For more details visit https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/